# JSONArray printing same values

Tags: json, jsp

The JSON object `obj` is inserted into the `JSONArray arr`, but when the Array is printed, the same object is printed for the number of iterations of `ResultSet`.

Can someone tell me what's the mistake?

```
try { 
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId,password);
    statement=connection.createStatement();
    statement2=connection.createStatement();
    String sql1 ="SELECT * FROM patient_detail where nurseid="+uidd;
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        obj.put("fname", resultSet.getString("fname"));
        obj.put("lname", resultSet.getString("lname"));
        obj.put("pid", resultSet.getString("pid"));
        obj.put("gender", resultSet.getString("gender"));
        obj.put("dob", resultSet.getString("dob"));
        obj.put("appdate", resultSet.getString("appdate"));
        obj.put("diseaseid", resultSet.getString("diseaseid"));
        list.add(obj);
    }

    String jsonText1 = JSONValue.toJSONString(list);
    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop you are mutating the *same* object in each iteration, and then adding the same object to the list. Any change you make in the next iteration to that object *is* a change to the object you stored in the list. So at the end your list contains *n* references to the same object.

To solve this, create a new object in each iteration:

```
try { 
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId,password);
    statement=connection.createStatement();
    statement2=connection.createStatement();
    String sql1 ="SELECT * FROM patient_detail where nurseid="+uidd;
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        obj = new JSONObject(); // <----
        obj.put("fname", resultSet.getString("fname"));
        obj.put("lname", resultSet.getString("lname"));
        obj.put("pid", resultSet.getString("pid"));
        obj.put("gender", resultSet.getString("gender"));
        obj.put("dob", resultSet.getString("dob"));
        obj.put("appdate", resultSet.getString("appdate"));
        obj.put("diseaseid", resultSet.getString("diseaseid"));
        list.add(obj);
    }

    String jsonText1 = JSONValue.toJSONString(list);
    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem could be the object "obj".
Try to create new obj on every iteration

```
    while(resultSet.next())
{
obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("fname", resultSet.getString("fname"));
obj.put("lname", resultSet.getString("lname"));
obj.put("pid", resultSet.getString("pid"));
obj.put("gender", resultSet.getString("gender"));
obj.put("dob", resultSet.getString("dob"));
obj.put("appdate", resultSet.getString("appdate"));
obj.put("diseaseid", resultSet.getString("diseaseid"));
list.add(obj);
    }

String jsonText1 = JSONValue.toJSONString(list);
connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Solved :)